# Subqueries without using the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

Here is my task:

List the full name of members, their DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE and the average of DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE for all members whose DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE is less than the average of all DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE.

Your query MUST contain a subquery. Do not use GROUP BY in your query.

Your result should be as shown below. Note that each member is only listed once.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(MEM_FNAME, " ", MEM_LNAME)) AS "Full Name",
detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE,
AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) AS "Average late fee" FROM membership
JOIN rental ON membership.MEM_NUM =  rental.MEM_NUM
JOIN detailrental ON rental.RENT_NUM = detailrental.RENT_NUM
WHERE detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE < 
    (SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental);
```

I need to have the AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) column show up. But I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 1: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'mimir.membership.MEM_FNAME'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
query returned no results!][1]
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIpzL.png  # This account is new so I can't post pictures yet

I suspect I'm supposed to use CASE but I'm pretty new to it so I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.

Comment: Put a subquery where AVG is.

Comment: Please provide sample data, otherwise it's difficult for people to contribute answers that fulfill your requirements. You are also missing the expected result when you say `Your result should be as shown below.`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       (CONCAT(MEM_FNAME, " ", MEM_LNAME)) AS "Full Name", 
       detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE, 
       (SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM MEMBERSHIP) AS "Average late fee"
FROM membership
     JOIN rental ON membership.MEM_NUM = rental.MEM_NUM
     JOIN detailrental ON rental.RENT_NUM = detailrental.RENT_NUM
WHERE detailrental.DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE <
(
    SELECT AVG(DETAIL_DAILYLATEFEE) FROM detailrental
);
```

Comment: I am wondering why this answer was not useful. And why the person who down voted my answer, wouldn't leave a comment for context.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this error: "In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'mimir.membership.MEM_FNAME'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"
query returned no results!
Thanks for your input though

Comment: Ahh, okay. Well, sorry about that buddy. Probably easier to figure out if there is way to test it. Thanks for the feedback Matthew. I appreciate it.

Comment: Side note, what kind of sql are you writing here? Because I wrote an example pretty close to yours in Oracle SQL Developer, and a different example in SSMS and both ran fine.

Comment: It's MySQL on a Mimir (university style software) platform

Comment: Give this answer a read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql. I am not familiar with what you are running into, but this article did reference your error. Some of the answers also reference how to disable only_full_group_by. Good luck!